# In App Maker, can you fake valueIsRecord with a dropdown field?

Tags: google-app-maker

In App Maker, what is the simplest way to achieve the same result with a dropdown box that you can with a suggest box, which can return the whole record when you make a selection giving you the ability to assign associated record values to other fields on the page?

Consider a data model with three fields, (Code, Description, and Severity). Add a dropdown box to select the Code. Have the selection, (probably using onValueChange or onValueEdit), write the selected Code's Description to a label field beside the dropdown box. The Code's Severity will also be used to affect the style in some way like background color or something, but for this answer, merely assigning the value to a scripting variable will be good enough. It's the record value access and assignment mechanism I am after.

Clarification: This data model will not be the page's datasource. It is a secondary reference table used for assigning a code to a ticket. You can also assume that a record value will be written to a field in the page's datasource as well.

I would appreciate the simplest low code solution as we will have non-programmers attempting this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you leave your value binding on the dropdown blank the following should work:

Set the options binding to:

```
@datasources.YourDatasource.items
```

You may want to consider changing the 'Names' binding to be the projection of a particular field in this datasource otherwise the values showing in your dropdown will only be the 'keys' from this datasource.

Then in your onValueEdit event you will gain access to individual fields like this:

```
var item = widget.datasource.item;
item.YourFieldToEdit1 = newValue.YourOtherDatasourceField1;
item.YourFieldToEdit2 = newValue.YourOtherDatasourceField2;
```

That would probably be the simplest way.

Comment: var item = widget.datasource.item;
     item.CC = newValue.CC;

it worked when assigning the value to a label text, but when I try to assign a value to a datasource item I get an error message of "Cannot set property 'CC' of null"
Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jeff That has been a recent problem unfortunately when using input widgets. For some reason it does not seem to recognize the datasource item anymore. Instead, do `widget.root.descendants.YourInputWidgetForField.value = newValue.YourField`, that should take care of that error and still put the appropriate value in the field.

Comment: The field is called CC in both tables.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I needed to make sure the datasource for the page was the (create) version. That seemed to open up it's ability to recognize the datasource fields for input. Thanks for your help.